# storing the result of a for loop into array and revrse it?

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to store the result of the for loop in an array then reverse it.
Example:
When I run the program and enter `5` the answer will be

> 54321

I want it to be

> 12345

```
int num;
int index = 0;
Console.Write("Number: ");
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int x = num; x > 0; x--)
{
    index = Convert.ToInt32(index + x);
    Console.Write(x);
}
Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum is: {0}", index);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You are better off, I think, not to parse this to an Int, but to GetBytes instead.  Then inside your for loop, Console.Write the array element corresponding to (num.Length-counter)

Comment: That (num.Length - counter) part of the comment assumed an incrementing counter.  I notice you have a decrementing counter, so for your for loop, Console.Write the (x-1) element on each iteration.

Comment: if you store it to an array you can use Enumerable.Reverse(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358497%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Console.Write("Number: ");
var num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());   // parse console input
var range = Enumerable.Range(1, num);   //generate array of values from 1 to num
var str = String.Concat(range.Select(x => x.ToString()));   //concatenate array of values
Console.WriteLine(str);     // write string
var sum = range.Sum(); // get sum of array
Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum is: {0}", sum);   // write sum
Console.ReadLine();   // pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For auto increment to total length

Use this

```
Console.WriteLine("Input length");
int length;
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
}
else
{
    int[] array = new int[length];
    for (int i = length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        array[length - i] = i;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Array is");
    foreach (var i in array)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse Array is");
    foreach (var i in array.Reverse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

To take every number from user, try this

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Input length");
    int length;
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out length))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
    }
    else
    {
        int[] array = new int[length];
        for (int i = length; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int input;
            Console.WriteLine("Input number");
            if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
                input = 0;
            }
            array[length - i] = input;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Array is");
        foreach (var i in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Reverse Array is");
        foreach (var i in array.Reverse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, none of those responses really would do what you asked for, but I mut say your example is really misleading.

Try this:

```
public int[] ArrayAndReverse(int Number)
{

    int[] data = new int[Number];
    int index = 
    for (int x = Number; x > 0; x--)
    {
        index = Convert.ToInt32(index + x);
        Console.Write(x);
    }
    return data.Reverse().ToArray();

}
```

now in your console code you can do:

```
Console.Write("Number: ");
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] data = ArrayAndReverse(number);
foreach(int i in data)
    Console.Write(i);
```

Also, not sure why your loop is already reversed, I suppose as I said this example is really misleading, else you can just use:

```
int[] data = Enum.Range(1, number).ToArray();
```

This will give you already the array in the right order.